# Upload 2GB file with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents, minio

I'm new to Apache HC and I'm wondering what is the best way to upload files of about 1 or 2 GB size.

I am using the Minio SDK to retrieve a presigned url from the server. After that, I am sending this presigned url to the client that will upload the specified file.

From Minio side, the max size per put operation is 5GiB so there should be no problems from minio side. My main concern is:

What would be the best way to achieve the upload of the file from Apache HC in order to get the best performance / less error prone behaviour?

I'm guessing that directly uploading a 2GB file is not a good option. Does the Apache HttpClient handles that upload in case an error occur? Is it convenient to upload the file as parts? How do I achieve that?

Comment: Is it compressed? Compressed transmission is possible. Also it might work if you have a zip file split in parts, as many unzippers can concatenate the parts (WinZip foir instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From Minio side, the max size per put operation is 5GiB so there should be no problems from minio side. My main concern is:
>
> What would be the best way to achieve the upload of the file from Apache HC in order to get the best performance / less error prone behaviour?
>
> I'm guessing that directly uploading a 2GB file is not a good option. Does the Apache HttpClient handles that upload in case an error occur? Is it convenient to upload the file as parts? How do I achieve that?

Minio server changed the maximum size to 16GiB per PutObject. Apache Client should handle uploading upto 2GiB without issues.